# Prevent saving the default value for category attribute

Tags: magento2, attributes, database, performance, eav

My module adds a custom dropdown attribute to categories. This attribute has many possible values, but in most cases (~90%) users will leave **the default value** in the attribute's field.

I want to make sure the attribute will not be saved in the database for categories in which user selected the default value. This will save some space in the database and (I hope) it will increase performance a little bit.

So I created a backend model for my attribute and in the `beforeSave` method I check the value of the attribute before it is finally saved in the database. If the current value is **the default value**, I replace it with an **empty string** `''`. See an example:

```
class ProductType extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\AbstractBackend
{
    const DEFAULT_VALUE = 'smartphones';

    public function beforeSave($object)
    {
        $attrCode = $this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode();
        $attrValue = $object->getData($attrCode);

        // If default value, don't save that attribute
        if ($attrValue === self::DEFAULT_VALUE) {
            $object->setData($attrCode, '');
        }
    }
}
```

**Is it the correct way to prevent saving the attribute in the database?**

Or **should I replace the value of the attribute with `null` instead of an empty string `''`?** Like this:

```
        if ($attrValue === self::DEFAULT_VALUE) {
            $object->setData($attrCode, null);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this will improve performance but to me you should use the unsetter instead of setting the value to an empty string or null:

```
$object->unsetData($attrCode);
```

This will definitely avoid any value being saved to the database for this particular attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php


namespace Moazzam\MaterialCount\Model\Config\Backend;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\AbstractBackend;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\AlreadyExistsException;
use Moazzam\MaterialCount\Model\MaterialFactory;
use Moazzam\MaterialCount\Model\ResourceModel\Material as ResourceModelMaterial;
use Moazzam\MaterialCount\Model\ResourceModel\Material\Collection;

/**
 * perfoam the action on backend model event
 *
 * Class AddIncrement
 */
class Count extends AbstractBackend
{
    const DEFAULT_VALUE = 'clothing_material';

    /**
     * @var Collection
     */
    private Collection $materialCollection;

    /**
     * @var MaterialFactory
     */
    private MaterialFactory $materialFactory;
    /**
     * @var ResourceModelMaterial
     */
    private ResourceModelMaterial $materialResourceModel;

    public function __construct(
        ResourceModelMaterial $materialResourceModel,
        Collection $materialCollection,
        MaterialFactory $materialFactory
    ) {
        $this->materialResourceModel=$materialResourceModel;
        $this->materialCollection=$materialCollection;
        $this->materialFactory=$materialFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @param $object
     * @return void
     * @throws AlreadyExistsException
     */
    public function afterSave($object)
    {
        $attrCode = $this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode();
        $materialId = $object->getData($attrCode);
        $material = $this->materialFactory->create();
        $this->materialResourceModel->load($material, $materialId);
        $count = (int)$material->getData('count');
        $countUpdate = $material->setData('count', $count+1);
        $this->materialResourceModel->save($countUpdate);
    }
}
```